# Проектирование приложения, организация Listener'ов

Tags: java, ооп, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Учу Java и создаю небольшой проект который содержит в себе форму. В ней есть множество кнопок, следовательно нужно много Listener'ов. Книга рекомендует реализовать их всех с помощью внутренних классов.

Стоит ли вынести все Listener'ы в отдельный класс и уже там реализовывать как внутренние классы (возможно есть какой-то шаблон проектирования) или оставить все в одном классе (в нем же происходит создание интерфейса)?

Как стоит организовать классы чтобы можно было легко добавлять новый функционал не копая при этом сотни строчек кода?

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо что поправили. это невозможно было читать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разные Listener'ы предназначены для разных целей. Вот в соответствии с этими целями и надо организовывать иерархию этих классов. А тот факт, что они реализуют интерфейс Listener, означает лишь, что, помимо всего прочего, они реагируют на нажатия кнопок и прочие действия пользователя. Это второстепенный признак, не надо на нем основываться.